# Bluetooth Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse keeps disconnecting

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I am using a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse which connects to the Windows 7 64-bit PC via bluetooth (PC has a USB bluetooth receiver). The mouse will disconnect several times a day for several seconds and then returns to normal.

The following warning message is logged in the system log:

```
Bluetooth HID device (28:18:78:5c:87:9e) either went out of range or became unresponsive.
```

I have searched for possible solutions and most people recommend [changing the power settings of the USB receiver](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c2a89ab-051d-44f3-ab01-1628a60141ed/bluetooth-mouse-issues) in Device Manager, however my USB receiver does not have any power options (no 'Power Settings' tab). I have also changed the Windows power settings to disable the "USB Selective Suspend" option.

Neither of these suggested solutions fix the problem and the mouse continues to disconnect randomly. I have also tried a different mouse (same model) and have replaced the batteries but the problem continues.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the most recent [Mouse and Keyboard Center](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-comfort-mouse#support) installed (select your OS with the first dropdown menu to see the download link)?

Comment: I am using native Windows 7 bluetooth mouse functionality. I will download that software and report back.

Comment: I am continuing to experience the same problem even after downloading the Mouse and Keyboard Center software. The problem has become worse in recent days and the system log continues to show the same error as quoted in the original question.

Comment: have same problem, found others to have the same issues too

Comment: Still happens to me about 1-2 times a day - have tried different USB Bluetooth receiver but same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with this device. It doesn't seem to matter what device it is paired to... after several hours of use it stops functioning after being paired with two different laptops, a tablet, or my desktop computer. It will work again after being removed from paired devices then re-paired.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you got this issue resolved. Just sharing this information from another blog which helped me solve similar issue.

> So i finally found the solution. I'm not even sure anyone will ever
>   enter this thread again, but I'll post it anyway, because this issue
>   drove me insane and i hope i can help other people in this situation.
>   SO, apparently windows 8.1 drivers are flawed, and in order to fix
>   this, you have to download windows 8 or 7 version of the driver. You
>   then have to run it in windows 7 compatibility mode(right
>   click-properties-compatibility tab-check the compatibility box and
>   select windows 7) and voila! Just install it as usual and you're good
>   to go.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Three suggestions to improve your answer: 1) Any time you quote or refer to a source, include a link to it for attribution and reference.  2) This isn't a universal solution and you say you used it for something similar, but not the exact problem.  Information about the exact issue that this was for and for which you had success is important.  3) Instead of quoting every word, use just the portions that provide the answer (leave out the unnecessary commentary before "apparently Windows 8.1 drivers...).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for about six months with my MSoft Sculpt mouse and a Dell Latitude E7470. Lots of random drop-outs for a few seconds, even with power saving disabled.

A few others have reported it seems to be happening to devices with an Intel Bluetooth chipset, which the Latitude has, so I went into Device Manager / Bluetooth / Intel Wireless Bluetooth and updated the driver from the one Win10 installed by default to the one supplied by Intel (v19.60.0.3) and checked the power saving was still off.

This worked fine for a week, then the drop-out of the Sculpt mouse happened again, but his time I noticed a pattern... I was listening to audio on my Jabra Bluetooth headset, which uses a separate Bluetooth USB dongle. It's possible the BT dongle is interfering with the built-in BT, so I've moved it to another USB port to put some distance between the aerials of the two devices.

I'll monitor this configuration and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Open Device Manager, select your Bluetooth driver, open its properties and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Answer (score -2):

If the PC can´t find the mouse driver it would say something like 'Unknown device'. What you need to do then, is to download the identity of the mouse so the PC would know which driver you are trying to connect.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question. The OP says the disconnect is for a few seconds only.

Comment: This answer doesn't pertain to this question. The problem was the mouse intermittently disconnecting, not a complete failure.